# Custom view disappear after adding it as subview to uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a custom view "BNRHyponsisView" that inherits from UIView. When I added to scroll view it just disappears, showing me the background color.

But the UITextField added to it displays just fine and scrolling is working fine too!
The references used strong, and I searched anyway and couldn't find an answer!

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.bhv = [[BNRHyponsisView alloc] init];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(40, 70, 240, 30);
    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    tf.placeholder = @"Hypnotize me!";
    tf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
    tf.autocorrectionType = YES;
    tf.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
    tf.delegate = self;
    [self.bhv addSubview:tf];


    UIScrollView *usv = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    usv.delegate = self;
    usv.pagingEnabled = NO;
    usv.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    usv.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    usv.contentSize = self.bhv.bounds.size;
    [usv addSubview:self.bhv];

    self.view = usv;
}
```

Comment: what is the frame of self.bhv? and what is its Background color?

Comment: The window frame, the default one.
It works perfectly If I set it as the view *with no scrolling*, the problem is when I add it to subview it just disappear.

Comment: ok. did you try this [self.view addSubview:usv];?

Comment: It calls the method "loadView" too many times until it crashes, I tried self.view = self.hbv; then ur line it calls it once but crash also.

Comment: Make global object of UIScrollView and check

Comment: what is crash message?

Comment: @Student same problem.

Comment: @MohitPopat stackoverflow.

Comment: what is usv's frame? firstly try to add simple view to your usv. i have doubt about if your scroll view works fine. If it works add your bhv without textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to set the frame dude.

```
self.bhv = [[BNRHyponsisView alloc] init]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);

self.bhv.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

**But Why it showed the UITextField?**

BNRHyponsisView frame will be 0,0,0,0(CGRectZero).But it still there, but not visible to your eyes. Very tiny(because of 0). But by default any UIView will not clip(clipsToBounds) the subviews if you created them programmatically. That's why it showing the UITextField.

Comment: No, Still same problem and the background still White.

Comment: change the color self.bhv.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; on viewdidappear

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame and background color for both

```
  1. self.bhv i.e UIView

   self.bhv = [[BNRHyponsisView alloc] init]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 350);
   self.bhv.backgroundColor = [UIColor redcolor];

  2. usv i.e UIScrollView
   usv = [[UIScrollView alloc] init]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400);
   usv.backgroundColor = [UIColor bluecolor];
```

Hope this can help you to debug your issue.

Comment: The background is blue, but still no BNRHyponsisView :/.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you have inherited BNRHyponsisView class from UIView? Try replacing it directly with UIView.